# Discord.js Promise { <pending> } endb

Tags: discord.js

So when i run my code in discord and put the prefix then i get **Promise { pending }** and not the value that i set to the endb.

My Code:

```
const Endb = require('endb');

const endb = new Endb({
  store: new Map(),
  namespace: 'Cache',
});

endb.set(msg.guild.id,"Random")
console.log(endb.get(msg.guild.id))
```

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`endb.get(msg.guild.id)` returns a [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) that you will have to [`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then).

```js
endb.get(msg.guild.id).then((data) => {
    console.log(data);
});
```

I also recommend you use something else other than `endb` since it is no longer maintained.